Checking linearity assumption in regression with quadratic terms
I have a few questions about checking the assumptions for linear regression: What is the best way to check linearity? Many recommendations I saw said to check scatterplots, but since linearity refers to the parameters and not the predictors, and there can be quadratic terms, a curve in a scatterplot wouldn't indicate a violation, so how do I do the visual assessment? Or is there a reliable quantitative way?
